# Hide button in CollectionViewCell after audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying

Tags: swift, button, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView within a ViewController. 
Each collectionViewCell in this collectionView has a button. After the button gets pressed, audio starts playing.
What i'd like to do is to hide the button after the audio finished playing.

How can i access the isHidden property of a button in a collectionViewCell within the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` delegate method?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {


func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("Did finish playing audio.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the `indexPath` of the cell where you want to hide the button. Then inside of your `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method just do the following:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: savedIndexPath) as? YourCustomCellClass {
        cell.button.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

or if you don't want the optional `if let cell` you could force unwrap like:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {    
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: savedIndexPath) as! YourCustomCellClass
    cell.button.isHidden = true
}
```

Note that `savedIndexPath` is the indexPath to the cell where you want to hide the button, and `YourCustomCellClass` is the subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` that you are using.

Comment: This will work if you only allow one sound to play at a a time. (And you'd probably need logic to prevent the user from tapping a different play button while a sound is currently playing.) If it's valid to play multiple sounds at a time you'd need a way to look up the indexPath based on the sound player. I was thinking you could create a dictionary of type `[AVAudioPlayer : IndexPath]` to look look up the IndexPath for a given sound player.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you audio files urls are unique then you can get `player.url` then find index of this url and then you can get indexPath.

For example

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

        print(player.url ?? "play")

        if let playerFileName = player.url?.lastPathComponent, let index = urls.index(of: playerFileName), let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? AudioCollectionViewCell {

            cell.playButton.isHidden = true
        }

    }
```

If this is not the case then save current plaing index somewhere then you can find cell at that index and hide/unhide button.